# Software to view all messages in one place regardless of source

Tags: email, chat

I get frustrated by the number of electronic communication channels we have these days – email (IMAP), FB Messenger, Whatsapp, iMessage, SMS, LinkedIn etc... it would be nice if as many of these as possible could be managed through one interface. Does such a thing exist, online or Mac?

This is only for home and light business use so I don’t want anything expensive.

Some requirements:

- be able to group messages by topic eg to say that Messenger conversation X is the same conversation as email Y.
- set a status eg “not complete, waiting for response from other person”.
- Store notes along with the messages (Outlook lets you edit an email which can be very useful but only applies to email).
- set some kind of expiry date (you know all the confirmation emails you get when you have ordered something off the internet? Wouldn’t it be nice to somehow manage those better than a stream of disparate messages in your inbox?).

Comment: Related, but not the same as my own question: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/25170/6957

Comment: See also [ping.fm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping.fm) and [WUPHF.com](https://www.forbes.com/sites/oliverchiang/2010/11/19/the-next-big-thing-in-social-media-wuphf-com/#6f28872746f6) and also [this](https://www.forbes.com/sites/oliverchiang/2010/11/19/the-office-spoofs-silicon-valley/#36687fa82698)